# Creating UIImage array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I've written code that gathers images from JSON requests and attempts to add them to an `NSMutableArray` to be used later in a table view. The problem is after adding the image objects to the array, the size of my `NSMutableArray` is 0. Here is the relevant code:

```
@implementation example{
    NSMutableArray *_placeImages;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    ...
    _placeImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void)JsonQuery {
    ...
    // Retrieve the results of the URL.
    dispatch_async(kMyQueue, ^{
    [self downloadImages];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableData) withObject:NULL waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

-(void)downloadImages{
     ...
     NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    [_placeImages addObject:image];
}
```

Comment: Have you initialized your array anywhere?  `_placeImages = [NSMutableArray new]`

Comment: Yes! I forgot to add that bit, but I do `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`. I wonder if it has to do with accessing the array from another thread.

Comment: Regardless your current problem, what you did here is not a correct way to collect and show images. I suggest you should use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for images to show on UITableView. It is easy to deploy and use. Almost everyone use it for UITableView + Image combo. It has own caching mechanism, you do not need to download same images again and again.

Comment: @SevP Are you sure `viewDidLoad` is firing **before** `downloadImages`?

Comment: Yes. I've also tried alloc/init immediately before adding objects. It must've been something else buried in my code, too much too paste here. I ended up using @mohacs suggestion which completely voided the question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

you must alloc NSMutableArray first:

```
_placeImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

or you can using lazy init:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)placeImages
{
    if (!_placeImages) {
       _placeImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _placeImages
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually do alloc and init in my viewDidLoad method, but this would certainly have been an issue.

Comment: If it not necessary to use NSMutableAarray, I recommend you using NSArray, because NSMutableArray have no thread safe. Beside, declare _placeImages as property, using lazy init and only access it with self.placeImages.
Hope this can help u, good luck.